# ls command is not working in bash.Error messages are getting displayed whenever I open bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The following log is getting displayed whenever I open bash

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os; print(os.pathsep.join([x for x in "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/neelesh/bin:/home/neelesh/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk":/snap/bin".split(os.pathsep) if not any([d for d in ['cturtle', 'diamondback', 'electric', 'fuerte'] if d in x])]))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
bash: cat: No such file or directory
bash: cat: No such file or directory
bash: python: No such file or directory
bash: grep: No such file or directory
bash: awk: No such file or directory
bash: dirname: No such file or directory
bash: /home/neelesh/setup.sh: No such file or directory
bash: dirname: No such file or directory
bash: /home/neelesh/setup.sh: No such file or directory
bash: dirname: No such file or directory
bash: /home/neelesh/setup.sh: No such file or directory
neelesh@neelesh-Lenovo-G580:~$ ls
bash: ls: No such file or directory
neelesh@neelesh-Lenovo-G580:~$ vim
bash: vim: No such file or directory
neelesh@neelesh-Lenovo-G580:~$
```

How to fix this ?

Thank you!!!

Comment: It appears you have included an erroneous statement in your `~/.bashrc` or your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` disrto dependent) or you have improperly edited your `PATH` variable causing it to no longer include `/bin:/usr/bin` resulting in `cat`, `python`, `grep`, `awk`, etc. to no longer be found in your `PATH`. Check those.

Comment: Thank you shelter for the edit..Can I know how you made the question proper..

Comment: Hi David thanks for reply .. I haven't changed anything..How could I make sure everything is right?

Comment: That's simple thank you :) ..echo path is showing empty.

Comment: Yup, that will do it every time. Find out where you are overwriting the default `PATH` and you will find your solution. Good luck. Depending on the distribution and packages installed, it should be something like `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl` (default on Archlinux)

Comment: How to find where the path is getting changed ...I am sorry if I am aking too simple question ..

Comment: No problem, we have all been there at one point in time. Just like any subject, you start by learning the basics and progress forward. You can simply do `export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:"` which will get you access to the commands you need to fix things. (you can add other path elements separated by a `colon` as required.) Let me know how it goes and I'm happy to get you going. To get a terminal, you should be able to simply hit `CTRL+ALT+F2` to drop to the default shell (waters muddied by recent X changes, `CTRL+ALT+F1` was standard), then `CTRL+ALT+F7` (or `CTRL+ALT+F1`) to get back.

Comment: Worst case scenario (if the default path got hosed), you will need to boot from your install .iso and `chroot` your system to fix the problem. See: [**What's the proper way to prepare chroot to recover a broken Linux**](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation)

Comment: Awesome..Thank you David

Comment: All commands are working, If I export path. But the problem is that, I always need to do that whenever I open a terminal. Is there any way I could find whether my Linux is broken or not?

Comment: That tells me you have a problem in either your default shell setup (either in `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash_profile`) or you are attempting to set `PATH` somewhere in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`. Do a `grep -n PATH` on each of the files and look at the output (with the `line number` listed) for each file to find out where `PATH` is set or reset. (remember the `profile` filename can differ based on your distribution)

Comment: The default `PATH` is generally set in `/etc/profile` so that `PATH` is only set for `login` shells and not duplicated every time you start another terminal. e.g. on openSuSE `grep -n PATH /etc/profile` reveals `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` and then several additions to it before `export PATH`.

Comment: Please clarify which distribution and version of Linux the system is running.

Comment: use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed what David C Rankin has mentioned in comments.

These are following the below steps:

1. opened terminal using cntrl+Alt+F2
2. Later added path step by step using export command

as 
    export PATH ="/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/neelesh/bin:/home/neelesh        /.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:    /bin:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"

3. Later using ctrl + alt + F7, I have exited the terminal.
4. restarted the system.

Now everything works fine.